# KDB - Extract pattern from string column in table

Tags: string, kdb

Table "t" has a column like this:

Column A:

```
ABC^AW=1a2b3c^FWJOGB

AW=2b3c^NJFW

CDE^AW=3c4d5e5f
```

Goal is to extract pattern "AW=*", and generate a new column with value after "=" sign, i.e.

Column B:

```
1a2b3c

2b3c

3c4d5e5f
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vs` operator to split each string in column `A`:

```
q)show t:([]A:("ABC^AW=1a2b3c^FWJOGB";"AW=2b3c^NJFW";"CDE^AW=3c4d5e5f"))
A
----------------------
"ABC^AW=1a2b3c^FWJOGB"
"AW=2b3c^NJFW"
"CDE^AW=3c4d5e5f"
q)update B:first each "^" vs/: last each "AW=" vs/: A from t
A                      B
---------------------------------
"ABC^AW=1a2b3c^FWJOGB" "1a2b3c"
"AW=2b3c^NJFW"         "2b3c"
"CDE^AW=3c4d5e5f"      "3c4d5e5f"
```

Comment: Thank you!  What's the best resource to learn about this kind of string operations? I spent sometime searching in the forum/google, but still didn't have much clue..

Comment: You can find several string operations on Kx's website https://code.kx.com/q/basics/strings/. Documentation for the `vs` operator: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/vs/, and another valuable operator that can take a list of strings and concatenate them with a specified delimeter: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/sv/

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer Jorge's answer and I would recommend and use that in practice, another approach which might help you to brush up on your string manipulation would be to treat your data as [key-value pairs](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/file-text/#key-value-pairs)

```
q)select{((!/)"S=^"0:x)`AW}'[A]from t
A
----------
"1a2b3c"
"2b3c"
"3c4d5e5f"
```

It's overkill for this use-case but highlights the usefulness of the built-in operators (once you know where to look!).